# Ionic app performance issues using PouchDB

Tags: angularjs, performance, ionic-framework, google-chrome-devtools, pouchdb

I'm debugging my Ionic app that uses `PouchDB`
One page is particularly slow at startup, inspecting it I've found that in 8s of recording ~99% of the CPU time is used by `pouchdb`.

`pouchdb` is wrapped in an angular service that I called `localdb`.

Using search in the `Timeline` tab of `chrome-dev-tools` I've found that `localdb` is mentioned 218 times and `pouchdb` 14972 times.

[image]
[image]

What can I do to understand what's going on?

**EDIT:** I've found that this code is 8x times slower on an android device (left column) than in the browser (right column)

```
console.time('READ--'+ID)
console.time('WRITE--'+ID)
LDB.query('my_index', { //stored index
    key: ID,
    include_docs: true
}).then(function(data) {
    console.timeEnd('READ--'+ID)
    //DO THINGS
    obj._rev = data._rev
    LDB.put(obj).then(function(ldata) {
        console.timeEnd('WRITE--'+ID)
    });
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think the Timeline search result is the count of references in the life span of the Timeline, where it gets passed through many different events (scripting, rendering, painting). It doesn't mean your code is calling the db function that many times. This search field is meant for filtering the type of Events on the Timeline, e.g. Parse HTML. See [How to Use the Timeline Tool: Search](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/evaluate-performance/timeline-tool?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3#search-records).

I tried to familiar myself with [PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/guides/documents.html) the last hour or two, but it's obviously quite a lot to get your head around. I managed to create a sample app from using the docs.

I found that you can get a lot of debugging information by using:

```
PouchDB.debug.enable('*');
```

It might give you an idea of where the bottleneck is.

https://jsfiddle.net/xmr5ksov/

[image: Debugging PouchDB]

The article [12 pro tips for better code with PouchDB](https://pouchdb.com/2014/06/17/12-pro-tips-for-better-code-with-pouchdb.html) might also give you some ideas on optimising both the database and the queries you are calling.

Comment: Hi Gideon, sorry for the late reply. I'll try to use debug `PouchDB.debug.enable('*');`. Thanks for help